# How do get an Ember.Select to be populated via Rails backend data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to write a select box in Ember, based on a Rails back end. When editing the model Recipes, I want to be able to select from a list of Sources in a dropdown. Right now in Ember I'm getting the message "The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed App.Sources" as a result of the following code.

I have tested the REST api and it is providing the response for Recipes and Sources both properly.

I'm new to Embers (and Javascript too, actually!) and I feel like I'm missing something basic. Thank you for any tips.

Here's my JS:

```
App.RecipeEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['sources'],
    selectedSource: null,

    actions: {
        save: function() {
            var recipe = this.get('model');
            // this will tell Ember-Data to save/persist the new record
            recipe.save();
            // then transition to the current recipe
            this.transitionToRoute('recipe', recipe);
        }
    }
});

App.RecipesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('recipe');
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        this.controllerFor('sources').set('content', this.store.find('source'));
    }
});

App.SourcesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('source');
  }
});

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: "api/v1"
});

App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  rating: DS.attr('number'),
  source: DS.belongsTo('source', {
    async: true
  }),
  page_number: DS.attr('number'),
  want_to_make: DS.attr('boolean'),
  favorite: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Source = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  authorLast: DS.attr('string'),
  recipes: DS.hasMany('recipe', {
    async: true
  })
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  return this.resource("recipes");
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  return this.resource("recipe", {
    path: "recipes/:recipe_id"
  });
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  return this.resource("recipeEdit", {
    path: "recipes/:recipe_id/edit"
  });
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter
});
```

And here's the view:

```
{{view Ember.Select
         contentBinding="controllers.sources.content"
         optionLabelPath="content.title"
         optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

UPDATE And here's the JSON:

```
{
    "recipes": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Did this make it through?",
            "url": "www.hellyeahitdid.com/high-five/",
            "rating": null,
            "source_id": null,
            "page_number": null,
            "want_to_make": false,
            "favorite": false
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Here's another totally crazy one for ya",
            "url": "http://www.example.com/recipe/1",
            "rating": null,
            "source_id": null,
            "page_number": null,
            "want_to_make": false,
            "favorite": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "A Sample Recipe",
            "url": "http://www.example.com/recipe/1",
            "rating": null,
            "source_id": null,
            "page_number": null,
            "want_to_make": false,
            "favorite": false
        }
    ]
}

{
    "sources": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Joy of Cooking",
            "author_last": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Everyday Food",
            "author_last": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does anything work yet (aka you have other templates?)

Comment: Thanks for your help @kingpin2k. It does work for Recipes---I can see an index and I can show a single record. However I haven't set up any views for the Sources. I'll see if creating those helps me uncover the problem.

Another piece of diagnostic info: in my Rails server log there's no sign that Ember is hitting the route or controller for Source. No 500, no thing. So I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong in Ember.

Thanks for the cleaner Router as well.

Comment: Routes define how ember should handle a route from the url.  The model hook is only hit when you visit that route.  Are you wanting to access sources from the recipes route?

Comment: Yep, that's right, I'm trying to select a Source from with a Recipe. They have associations set in Rails and Ember both.

Comment: I continued trying to research this, and still haven't found an answer. I updated the code above with slightly different view code and changes to the first two calls. I'm getting a select box to appear without any errors in the Ember console, but there's nothing in there to select. I know the JSON response, if one were happening, would have a record.

Comment: will you add the json?  I'll wire it up so you can see it.  The sources controller is only built if you hit that route.

Comment: Added. Thank you again for the help! I asked the question on IRC and got some good tips too. I see I was using the wrong adapter for one.

Comment: This should get you started http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/74/edit

Comment: btw, `source_id` should be `source` in your ajax

Comment: Thanks kingpin2k, I really appreciate it. There's lots there to dig into. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to javacript/ember, here's an example using a select.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/69/edit

you'll notice the i don't quote real properties, and do quote strings

```
{{ view Ember.Select
      content=someSource
      optionValuePath='content.id'
      optionLabelPath='content.title'
 }}
```

Additionally that appears to be a very old version of Ember Data.  You may consider updating. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Your routing can go in a single call

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("recipes");
  this.resource("recipe", { path: "recipes/:recipe_id"}, function(){
    this.route('edit');
  });
});
```

This should get you started

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/74/edit